# jquery select parent css

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do I select the first css class `.CategoryText` outgoing from `<p>`?

```
<div class="CategoryText NoPadding">
    text
</div>

<div class="CategoryText NoPadding">
    <p>text</p>
</div>
```

--

```
$(".CategoryText > p").parent().parent().css({"display": "none",});
```

It doesn't work. This will select all outgoing from the first class `.CategoryText`. I want to select only one - the first class `.CategoryText`.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Try to explain it better.

Comment: which one you want to hide?

Comment: do you want to add display none to `CategoryText `?

Comment: should only one .parent() if you're trying to select CategoryText

Comment: i have two classes CategoryText. in the secound CategoryText is an p tag. so i will outgoing from p select the first CategoryText class. p < CategoryText < CategoryText

Comment: you want the CategoryText before the CategoryText  with the p in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try prev()/next()

```
$(".CategoryText > p").parent().prev('.CategoryText').css({"display": "none"});
```

Answer (score 2):

All of the text is disappearing because you're using one too many `.parent()` calls. jQuery also has a built-in `.hide()` convenience method to do set `display: none` for you.

Try this:

`$('.CategoryParent>p').parent().hide();`

Answer (score 1):

this will select the first class `$(".CategoryText:first-of-type")`

https://jsfiddle.net/hjbj5do4/1/

Answer (score 0):

Would take a look at

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_traversing_descendants.asp

This will help you find out proper jQuery traversing selectors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if I got this right.
So the `.CategoryText > p` selects all `p` elements being immediate childs of elements having class `CategoryText`. With `:first` you select only the first matched element.
Then, with `.parent()` ou select its parent, so the element having the class `CategoryText`.

Here is a demo:

```js
var e = $('.CategoryText > p:first').parent();
console.log(e.length + " mached element"); // only one matched item
console.log(e.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<div class="CategoryText NoPadding">
  text
</div>

<div class="CategoryText NoPadding">
  <p>text 1</p>
</div>
<div class="CategoryText NoPadding">
  <p>text 2</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the first element of class `CategoryText` like that:`$(".CategoryText:nth-child(1)")`